# how to delete lines between specific signs in python?

Tags: python

i need to search a bunch of text files which may contain content in this forms:

```
//for nv version
        tf = new TextField();
        tf.width = 600;
        tf.height = 300;
        tf.textColor = 0x00ffff;
        tf.mouseEnabled = false;
        this.addChild(tf);
        Sys.__consoleWindowFuncBasic = log;
//nv end
```

and delete the part between the 2 lines and save them.

i split the text into lines, and check the text line by line,thus make the work very heavy,is there any easy way for doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can try to use the regular expression to replace the match lines to an empty line.
@yuwang provided a `sed` version, here is a `python` version([python re docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)):

```
>>> import re
>>> s = """some words
... other words
... //for nv version
...     tf = new TextField();
...     tf.width = 600;
...     tf.height = 300;
...     tf.textColor = 0x00ffff;
...     tf.mouseEnabled = false;
...     this.addChild(tf);
...     Sys.__consoleWindowFuncBasic = log;
... //nv end
... yet some other words
... """
>>> p = r"//for nv version(.*?)//nv end\n"  # reluctant instead of greedy
>>> print re.sub(p, "", s, flags=re.S) # use re.S to make `.` matchs `\n`
some words
other words
yet some other words
```

Comment: I suppose you would like to make your quantor reluctant instead of greedy.

Comment: shoudl be //for nv version(.*?)//nv end\n?

Comment: @user2003548 yes, answer's updated. Sorry for the first version.

Answer (score 4):

Check this out

```
beginMarker = "//for nv version"
endMarker = "//nv end"

include = True
with open('path/to/input') as infile, open('path/to/output', 'w') as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        if include:
            if line.strip() != beginMarker:
                outfile.write(line)
            else:
                include = False
        else:
            if line.strip() == endMarker:
                include = True
```